# Cómo editar una tabla al intentar cerrar el navegador o pestaña

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Buenas pues tengo una tabla en u a base de datos mysql que me guarda la hora de ingreso y salida de los usuarios de un sistema pero al marcar el cierre del navegador el usuario se queda sin su cierre de sesión, mi pregunta es

Hay alguna manera de que cuando yo cierre el navegador me guarde un valor en una tabla de una base de datos antes que se cierre?

Comment: Hay alguna una manera? Seguro que sí.

Comment: Yo crearía un servicio en el back que se esté ejecutando cada X minutos. Una tabla en la bbdd con las sesiones abiertas y si al pasar esos X minutos comprobar la ultima hora de conexión de esas sesiones y si alguna se pasa de los minutos que tu decidas, pues cerrarlas. En cada petición al back puedes enviar por headers o por donde sea el id de la sesión e ir actualizando la ultima hora de conexión para que no se le cierre.

Answer (score 1):

**Respuesta corta**

No, haz que tus sesiones tengan una vigencia en tiempo.

**Respuesta larga**

Lo más seguro como desarrollador es hacer que tus sesiones caduquen, recuerda que siempre se le puede ir la luz al usuario o se le puede apagar el internet o apaga la computadora con un botonazo y eso es imposible de cachar en el mundo web.

Lo más cercano a cachar si un explorador es cerrado con javascript es mediante el evento onbeforeunload del window, el problema es que esta función cacha la acción de cerrar, cambiar o refrescar de página, (o sea no sólo de cerrar la ventana), y afortunadamente través de los años los exploradores han cambiado el funcionamiento del método, previniendo comportamientos como no permitir que el usuario pueda cerrar una ventana o abrir infinitamente otras ventanas cuando se intenta cerrar la ventana actual, por lo que en un futuro pueda no servir tu código de javascript o corra en todos los navegadores de forma esperada.

Algo que igual y te puede servir como comente es usar el evento onbeforeunload pero necesitarías hacer muchas más cosas para cachar que no hayan mas ventanas abiertas o que el evento sea cerrar una ventana y no cambiar de pagina o refrescarla. Te muestro un ejemplo de javascript+html del método onbeforeunload:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aviso cierre ventana</title>
<script>
    
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "/PaginaRegistrarAccion.php?HacerLoggout=si");
        xhttp.send();
    
    };
    
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Contenido de página
    </body>
</html>
```